# Can't highlight text in foreign object when d3 drag is attached

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

So I have a foreignobject element inside an svg group. I've attached a drag event to that foreignobject using d3.call(d3.drag) on that object and it works great.

Now I want to be able to highlight text in a text area inside that foreign object.

I tried e.preventDefault and e.stopPropogation in the textarea for onMouseDown, onDragStart, and onDragEnter and none of them stopped the dragging event from occuring.

How do I stop the drag event from occuring inside the textarea of my draggable foreignobject, so I can drag highlight text?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply moving the selector of the drag event to only the header of my window.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I believe I am facing the same issue